# Add CSS class to fieldset div element without extending the template

Tags: 8, theming, webforms

I only want to add a class to the  inside the `fieldset` from `fieldset.html.twig`. It's a bit overkill to extend the template for just to add a class.

How can I achieve this with a preprocess function?

```
function mytheme_preprocess_fieldset(&$variables) {
// $variables['children']['attributes']['class'][] = 'mb-4';
}
```

Comment: Did you check the content of $variables['children']? It might be already rendered, in which case you are too late and need to find the preprocess hook of the template containing the div which was rendered earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Under a fieldsets 'Advanced' settings tab, you can add custom attributes to the fieldset.

[image]